# How do you solve the glib.h not found error when building webkit?

Tags: webkit

I follow the instructions at: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WebKit
I get an error when running `./autogen.sh --prefix=/usr` stating that:

```
conftest.c:28:18: fatal error: glib.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

Answer (score 0):

You most likely didn't installed the development libraries as indicated. Run this and try again:

```
sudo apt-get install subversion gtk-doc-tools autoconf automake libtool libgtk2.0-dev libpango1.0-dev libicu-dev libxslt-dev libsoup2.4-dev libsqlite3-dev gperf bison flex libjpeg62-dev libpng12-dev libxt-dev autotools-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev libenchant-dev libgail-dev
```

Comment: I had done this also, but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

open your terminal and type as

```
      apt-cache search glib
```

it will show you some packages and install glib package with

```
    sudo apt-get install packagename
```

ps: i am off to my ubuntu system to give exact command

Comment: After doing these things and running "apt-cache search glib" it comes back with lots of packages so I run the ones like libglib2.0-dev and libglib2.0-0, but I still get the same error. I'm new to Ubuntu so I would like to find the Makefile such that I can add the -I compiler flag to reference glib.h, but I can't find it.

Comment: I also can't find conftest.c